# Apple TV 3rd generation. How to download to device

Tags: appletv

[image]

I’m fed up of seeing this sort of thing. How can I download a purchase to the Apple TV and it not be in the cloud. Thanks

Comment: Are you having network/wifi problems?  Are you trying to play a local file or a show you purchased from iTunes?  You say you're tired of seeing this message and that usually means network issues, can you watch this show on any other device?

Comment: Network is usually fine. I bough this on iTunes. Doesn’t the Apple TV have some internal memory to store some of my purchases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple TV 3rd Gen has no true storage at all & only 512MB RAM - it was discovered it does actually have a 'hidden' 8GB, but presumably that will be caching content for immediate use rather than storing a movie you watched previously.

38 minutes to download a movie/TV show would indicate your internet connection is struggling.

From **[Everymac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/apple-tv/specs/apple-tv-3rd-generation-early-2013-specs.html)** -

> *Officially, the third generation Apple TV models have no internal storage. However, third-parties have determined that they actually have 8 GB of flash memory to cache content, just like the second generation Apple TV.